# Suggestions for a Live chat software on websites for customer support?

Tags: chat, customer-service

Recommendations needed.

We want to get in touch with customers via live chat.

Requirements:

- chat window customisable to mingle with website theme (colors etc)
- preferably the window should be within webpage and not only pop-out/popup.
- ease of use by customer
- minimally intrusive
- should have triggers/Alerts to backend side. for ex: user is unable to fill-up signup form or something, we should be able to offer help to user and this chat window automatically shows to user.

What is the cost ?

**UPDATE**:
After R&D we also narrowed down to comm100 and liveperson, and we will go with comm100.
LP is best commerical soln. but comm100 is a good free soln. We go with comm100 as starting point.

But it gives out exceptions alerts sometimes in the dashboard. Can it be configured for chat invitations triggered on certain conditions. Currently only a timebased trigger is available. Any other major difference between these two ?

Comment: Suggestion - Edit the title. Don't ask for the "best." Edit it to ask what are some chat software... Asking what people believe is the best this and that is a matter of opinion. This is a conflict of the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: I asked this question a while ago: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/live-chat-solutions. It was originally intended to be for free/foss solutions only, but I later opened it to commercial solutions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.comm100.com/ is a good option and free too.

When we were thinking about live chat for our site we narrowed down to Liveperson and Comm100, then later on selected Com100 as it has various customization options and above all free of cost (eventually we didn't implement any chat support because of various political reasons in our office).

Comment: Actually we also narrowed down to these both only, and we will go with comm100. But it gives out exceptions alerts sometimes in the dashboard. Can it be configured for chat invitations triggered on certain conditions. Currently only a timebased trigger is available. Any other major difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1):

http://solutions.liveperson.com is the best i have experienced. Cost is hard to say as they work to a budget so can be lower or higher.

Can see a demo on their site, and they tick all the above required fields